Filter subdocuments by multiple criteria
I have a collection "fruits" like this:
db={
  "fruits": [
    {
      "name": "Banana",
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "green",
          "props": [
            {
              "uid": 1,
              "grade": 3
            },
            {
              "uid": 3,
              "grade": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "color": "yellow",
          "props": [
            {
              "uid": 2,
              "grade": 1
            },
            {
              "uid": 1,
              "grade": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "color": "brown",
          "props": [
            {
              "uid": 1,
              "grade": 3
            },
            {
              "uid": 4,
              "grade": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

available_prop_uids = [1,4,5]
Now I want to filter the documents in an aggregation by multiple criteria in case the array variants.props is not empty:
a.) Filter array variants by max props.grade: variants should contain only subdocuments that contain at least one prop with the max prop value from all variants per document. In the example, the variants with color green and brown have a prop with grade 3, which is the highest grade among all variants for the document Banana. Therefore, the variants array is reduced to two subdocuments, with color green and brown.
b.) Filter array variants by available_prop_uids: Furthermore, variants should contain only subdocuments where the set of prop.uids is a subset of available_prop_uids.
Variant green is now removed from the array since it contains a prop with uid 3 which is not in available_prop_uids.
Desired outcome:
    [{
      "name": "Banana",
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "brown",
          "props": [
            {
              "uid": 1,
              "grade": 3
            },
            {
              "uid": 4,
              "grade": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]

Thanks for your help!

Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Also, it's unclear if you want Filter A & B as part of the same query or if you're asking two separate questions together for the same example data.

A & B should be part of the same query. This is what i tried so far on point A: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xlv4yu08Mk3
I am stuck on how to apply the filtering logic to the nested array of props inside of the variant subdocuments.

something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/cSy1Ru0urKL

@cmgchess beautiful, that works! Thanks!

@LucienChardon Your example doesn't have the field props but your question does. Is it an actual field in your data?

guess u can even  combine the 2,3 stages https://mongoplayground.net/p/P7BZcfn0YO-

@aneroid I played with the filtering, I did not get to the point to include the props array in the example yet.

@cmgchess When there is a document where the array variants.props is empty and there is no other variant present, is there a way to leave the document as it is? Like here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DNHPIp5gi-l

So the expected result would be that the Orange document contains the variant {         "color": "orange",         "props": []       } as in the collection, untouched

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y_MGV0_ENak use a $or to short circuit

if u want u can post an answer or let me know if u want me to

@cmgchess please post the answer, it is your efforts!

here are the steps i took.

Find the maximum props.grade value and save it in a temporary field.
Filter such that at least 1 in the props array has grade value equal to max
Filter such that an array of props.grade values is a subset of the input list
Remove the temp field created on step 1

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      max: {
        $max: {
          $map: {
            input: "$variants",
            as: "variant",
            in: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$$variant.props",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                  $cond: [ { $gt: [ "$$this.grade", "$$value" ] }, "$$this.grade", "$$value" ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      variants: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "variant",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              { $eq: [ { $size: "$$variant.props" }, 0 ] },
              {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$variant.props",
                    as: "prop",
                    in: { $eq: [ "$$prop.grade", "$max" ] }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      variants: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "variant",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              { $eq: [ { $size: "$$variant.props" }, 0 ] },
              {
                $setIsSubset: [
                  {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$variant.props",
                      as: "prop",
                      in: "$$prop.uid"
                    }
                  },
                  [ 1, 4, 5 ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "max" }
])

playground
Steps 2 and 3 can be combined to 1 if needed. will remove an extra looping step https://mongoplayground.net/p/LdmTI45VYvJ
